# How to update state of nested object by id with input select method?

Tags: reactjs, input

need to update cart state with custom key (index or productID)

```
state = {
cart:[
      0:{
        "productID": 1234,
        "size",''
        "color":'',
        "price":1599
      },
  1:{
        "productID": 1162,
        "size",''
        "color":'',
        "price":2899
      },
};
```

When client select value for color cart item need to be updated

```
handleChange = input => e => {
    this.setState({ [input]: e.target.value });
  };
```

```
render(){
 <NativeSelect
  input={<Input name="color" />}
  // cart[item.productId]
  onChange={handleChange(this.state.cart[0].color)}
  >      
 <option value="">---</option>
 <option value="red">red</option>
 <option value="green">green</option>        

 </NativeSelect>

}
```

I just need syntax or method how to point my item in cart and update the state

Comment: Hi Djordje, please try my solution below and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `onChange` handler needs to know what product is going to be updated. So define a function that takes both the `selected` color and the matching `productID` as arguments.

See working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-hellman-6l20c

### Working Code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { NativeSelect, Input } from "@material-ui/core";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    cart: [
      {
        productID: 1234,
        size: "",
        color: "",
        price: 1599
      },
      {
        productID: 1162,
        size: "",
        color: "",
        price: 2899
      }
    ]
  };

  handleOnChange = (e, id) => {
    const cartCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.cart));

    let productToUpdate = cartCopy.find(product => product.productID === id);

    productToUpdate.color = e.target.value;

    this.setState(
      {
        cart: cartCopy
      },
      () => console.log(this.state.cart)
    );
  };

  renderCartSelection = () => {
    const { cart } = this.state;

    return cart.map(product => {
      return (
        <div>
          {product.productID}:{" "}
          <NativeSelect
            onChange={e => this.handleOnChange(e, product.productID)}
          >
            <option value="">---</option>
            <option value="red">red</option>
            <option value="green">green</option>
          </NativeSelect>
        </div>
      );
    });
  };

  render() {
    return <div>{this.renderCartSelection()}</div>;
  }
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you get and mutate the entire state.cart object in your handleChange it might make it easier to find out what is going on

```
handleChange = input => e => {
    const newState = {...this.state.cart}
    newState[0].color = e.target.value
    console.log(newState)
    this.setState(newState);
  };
```